# Ruby on rails: Updating attribute on an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

In my controller I have the following:

```
def sort
    params[:order].each do |key,value|
      Question.find(value[:id]).update_attribute(:order,value[:order])
    end
    render :nothing => true
  end
```

This works perfectly to update the order column for the 'Question' item.

However i've now moved the order column to a new table 'question_sections' which is associated to Questions.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :sections, :through => :question_sections
    belongs_to :section
    has_many :question_sections
    default_scope { order(order: :asc) }

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :section, :reject_if => :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :question_sections, :reject_if => :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

I'm trying to adapt the sort function to update the 'order' column in 'question_sections' but am having trouble with it.

Any help on what the function should look like?

Comment: I may be wrong here but if Question has nested_attributes for question_sections then the order_id should be present in the `params[:question_sections_attributes]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are using nested attributes, you shoud call the `includes` method, and then iterate over each question_sections:

```
def sort
    params[:order].each do |key,value|
        questions = Question.includes(:question_sections).find(value[:id])
        questions.question_sections.each { |q| q.update_attribute(:order,value[:order]) }
    end
    render :nothing => true
end
```

This breaks the problems into 2 parts, load all the question_sections needed:

### 1) Load all the question_sections of a question:

```
questions = Question.includes(:question_sections).find(value[:id])
```

**Question Load**

> SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]

**QuestionSections Load**

> SELECT "question_sections".* FROM "question_sections" WHERE "question_sections"."question_id" IN (1)

### 2) update this question_sections

```
questions.question_sections.each { |q| q.update_attribute(:order,value[:order]) }
```

**QuestionSections Update**

> UPDATE "question_sections" SET "order" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "question_sections"."id" = ?  [["order", "different order now"], ["updated_at", "2017-03-09 13:24:42.452593"], ["id", 1]]

Comment: Thanks for this, but this updates the questions table, but I want it to update the questions_sections table.

Comment: That's done it, thank you! I had tried something similar, but didn't do the each on 'question_sections'.

Comment: I understand, the `.update_attribute` method is a instance method, so it must be performed in instances.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are using nested_attributes for `Question` model here then Rails should automatically update the nested params for `QuestionSection`

The controller should look something like this:

```
def sort
  @question = Question.find_by(id: params[:id])
  @question.update_attributes(question_params)
end

private

def question_params
  params.require(:question).permit!
end
```

The parameters received to the controller should be like :

```
params = { question: {
  abc: 'abc', question_sections_attributes: [
    { order_id: 1, ... },
    { order_id: 2, ... },
    { order_id: 3, ... }
  ]
}}
```

I hope this helps :)